# Why is 5px being inserted between img and td

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, html-email

Here is the code:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbhL7ucz/)

I believe I have removed all spacing, but the `td` is still `305px` and the `img` is `300px` `height`.

Even if I try:

```
<td height="300">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=56&txt=600%C3%97600&w=600&h=600" alt="" width="300">
</td>
```

or

```
<tr height="300">
```

On the containing `<tr>`.

This is completely ignored and the `td` stays at 305px?

Comment: Have you used any CSS at all? If you haven't, there's some default paddings on tables in HTML.

When I opened your Fiddle and selected the element with the odd padding; I noticed there was a font-size set as well. I changed this to 0px and it seemed to fix your odd paddings. 

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/H36LrNX.png)

Answer (score 3):

because `img` is an inline element and has `vertical-align:baseline` therefore creates a gap.

So you either can:

- `display:block` in `img`

or  set

- `vertical-align:bottom`

Also you don't need 2 `style`s tag, neither don't you need to duplicate the `body` rule with new properties, just put all in one `body` rule.

Note: careful if you are creating this for html-email, the CSS which is not inline (above `body`) some email clients such as gmail will strip it, make sure you put it all inline or you use some toll that will do that for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Battersea Studios</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #outlook a {
      padding: 0;
    }
    body {
      width: 100% !important;
       margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
       -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
      text-size-adjust: none;
    }
    .ReadMsgBody {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass {
      width: 100%;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    img {
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 0;
      display: block
    }
    a {
      border: 0;
    }
    hr {
      width: 20px;
      text-align: left
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:600px;font-size:20px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="color:white;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=56&txt=600%C3%97600&w=600&h=600" alt="" width="300">
            </td>
            <td style="background-color:#E66977;vertical-align:top;">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="240">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img src="imgs/spacer-pink.jpg" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong>urtyryhry</strong>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img src="imgs/spacer-pink.jpg" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    ryhryhjtyhjty
                    <br>tyjtyjtyjty
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#1EA553;vertical-align:top;">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="240">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img src="imgs/spacer-green.jpg" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <strong>F</strong>
                  </td>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img src="imgs/spacer-green.jpg" alt="">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      rthrthrth
                      <br>ryhryhryht
                      <br>hryhryhryt
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=56&txt=600%C3%97600&w=600&h=600" alt="" width="300">
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=56&txt=600%C3%97600&w=600&h=600" alt="" width="300">
              </td>
              <td style="background-color:#EA752E;vertical-align:top;">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="240">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img src="imgs/spacer-orange.jpg" alt="">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <strong>rtyryry</strong>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img src="imgs/spacer-orange.jpg" alt="">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      rryu56u
                      <br>ryuryuy
                      <br>uryuryuyrt
                      <br>ytyutyuty
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`img` is `inline` element and it takes few extra pixels on bottom by default. Use `display: block` for `img` to remove this space:

```
table img {
    display: block;
}
```